# Is it possible to change the first 1 or 2 letters of a string using Update statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a query that can change 1 or 2 letter of a string value using the update statement.

It goes something like this:

```
UPDATE  
    tableName  
SET  
    LEFT(Col1, 2)='EX' -- Just a sample, only works for Select statement  
WHERE  
    Col1 like ('%MPLE')
```

Result will change every string value with '-MPLE' suffix becomes 'EXMPLE'.

Comment: Although it can be implicitly understood, please state your RDBMS.

Answer (score 4):

```
DECLARE @pattern AS VARCHAR(10)--you may need to change the length
DECLARE @changeto AS VARCHAR(2)--you may need to change the length
SET @pattern = '%MPLE'
SET @changeto = 'EX'


UPDATE 
   tableName
SET
   Col1 = CASE 
              WHEN LEN(Col1) > 2                   --If Col1 has more than 2 characters
              THEN @changeto + RIGHT(Col1,LEN(Col1)-2)  --Update the first two characters
              ELSE @changeto                            --Else replace the whole word
          END
WHERE
   Col1 like (@pattern)
```

Comment: There is no point checking with `LEN(Col1)>2` because Col1 is already at least 4 characters.

Comment: @Kaf This is indeed implied by the `where`, but this could be as well turned in a generic.

Comment: Now think if `Col1 = 'ABCDEF-MPLE'` and what would be the results?

Comment: @Kaf 'EXCDEF-MPLE' Isn't that what `I need a query that can change 1 or 2 letter of a string` means?

Comment: I think he needs to change everything with `'%MPLE'` suffix to `'EXAMPLE'` and your answer is not doing that. I am not sure if I am missing anything here. May be OP can update. Also, when you filter with `WHERE Col1 Like '%MPLE'` you don't have to check the length >2 in the case statement.

Comment: @Kaf Don't get me wrong, i totally agree with not having to check for length in that particular case. I just wanted to show something more generic. In fact i will update my answer just to make this clearer. By the way you are right that OP should make clear what he really wants, as your answer is more straightforward if `EXMPLE` should be the output.

Comment: I thought it was worth mentioning, that was it. Good day !

Answer (score 2):

**Hi,
Below will be helpful to you....**

> ```
> DECLARE @ReplaceString CHAR(2)
> SET @ReplaceString = 'RS'
>
> UPDATE TableName SET ColName = REPLACE(ColName, LEFT(ColName, 2),@ReplaceString)
> WHERE LEFT(ColName,2) = @Parameter
> ```

=> here LEFT(ColName,2) return first two character of ColName column Value. So As per that you can pass @Parameter value to true the condition.

**Thank you,
Vishal Patel**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update every record with `%AMPLE` suffix to `EXAMPLE` why not try

```
UPDATE  tableName  
SET  Col1 = 'EXAMPLE'
WHERE Col1 like ('%MPLE')
```